# Why does it not work ? Can Someone please explain Memory Allocation, static/non static, global/local variables/ deepcopy used in stack

Tags: java, recursion, stack, tail-recursion

It is a simple recursive function to print array elements in reverse.

When I call the function above the print statement, it gives me index -1 `outOfBoundException`.
When I print before calling the function, it seems to work. I suppose it is somewhat related to deepcopy of the variables but I do not know the correct Explanation. Can someone please provide me with the appropriate answer?

```
 int[] arr = {1,2,3};
 int n = arr.length;
 print(arr,n-1);
```

This gives error:

```
public static void print(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        if(n<0)
            return;

        print(arr,--n);
        
        System.out.println(arr[n]);
    }
```

This does not:

```
public static void print(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        if(n<0)
            return;
        
        System.out.println(arr[n]);

        print(arr,--n);
    }
```

Comment: `--n` mutates the variable and for the last element your trying to print index `-1`. You could change `--n` with `n - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Typing `--n` is different from typing `n--`.

The first will decrement the value, and then read the value.
Whereas, the second one will read the value, and then decrement it.

More information on Java Unary Operators can be found here.
[Assignment, Arithmetic, and Unary Operators (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

The reason that one method is returning an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is because upon the last recursive iteration, the `n < 0` condition is met, thus, the function exits at `print` with a negative value for `n`.

```java
if (n < 0) return;  /* <- recursion is taking place */
print(arr, --n);    /* <- between these two statements */

/* when print exits, n is -1 here */
System.out.println(arr[n]);
```

Comment: Yes but that isnt what confuses me here. I wanted to know why does printing first and then calling recursively gives error of indexOutOfBounds -1 but calling first and printing later gives no error

Comment: @DhruvChopra, sure, I've updated my answer to include more information.